# How to uninstall npm from WSL

Tags: npm

I was having trouble with executing tsc commands, but adding tsc to the front works. I was advised to uninstall npm and do a clean install. I am doing all this in WSL.

I tried doing this by following a post saying to run the commands:

sudo apt-get remove nodejs npm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

after the first command i got this:

[image: first command]

then i still ran the other 2 commands and got this:

[image: second command]

[image: third command]

but it says that I still have npm installed with npm -v

I tried to also do the sudo npm uninstall npm -g command, but my terminal said that sudo: npm: command not found.